# How to grab the data in front of seasonId= from a big string variable?

Tags: javascript

hi all i got a big string variable(var bigstring) and i want to grab data in front of seasonId= .for example somewhere in my bigstring i have this:seasonId=5567
and i want to grab Only 5567 value(also i want to remove any space after 5567 value if there is any space) and put it in another variable? How this can be done ?

Answer (score 0):

do you mean:

```
var myRegexp = /seasonId=(\d+)/;
var match = myRegexp.exec(yourBigString); 
console.log( match ); //will give 5567
```

Comment: thanks but this give me output like this seasonId=5567,5567 while i only want 5567!in my big string may be there is another 5567 but i only want the one that has seasonId= in front of it.In my bigstring there is only one seasonId=